# Hive SELECT records from 1 hour ago

Tags: hive, hiveql, unix-timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a hive table that contains a column called timestamp. The timestamp is a bigint field generated from java `System.currenttimemillis()`. I suppose it should be in UTC. Right now I am trying to select records from 1 hour ago. I know in MySQL you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetimefield >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

In hive, it seems like `NOW()` is missing. I did some searching and find `unix_timestamp()`. I should be able to get the current UTC time in milliseconds by doing a `unix_timestamp()*1000`.

So if i want to get records from 1 hour ago I am thinking about doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM hivetable WHERE datetimefield >= (unix_timestamp()*1000-3600000);
```

Can someone suggest if it's the right way to approach this problem? Also what if I want to select like 1 day ago? Seems inconvenient to convert that to milliseconds. Any help or suggested readings will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [`unix_timestamp()`](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/#from_unixtime) gets you the seconds elapsed since Unix epoch. You can subtract 60*60*1000 milliseconds and compare your field to get the desired records.

For Hive 1.2.0 and higher you can use `current_timestamp`

```
select * 
from hivetable 
where 
     datetimefield >= ((unix_timestamp()*1000) - 3600000);
```

For 1 day,convert the milliseconds to date format and use [`date_sub`](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/#DATE_SUB_string_date_int_days)

```
select * 
from hivetable 
where 
     from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(datetimefield,'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')) >= 
     date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),1);
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind clarify why you want to do a from_unixtime? Also what's the point of doing unix_timestamp(datetimefield,'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')? Do I need to do that if my datetimefield is already in millisecond eg 1529600214530? Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned that your field type is in string format

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's in bigint.

Comment: No you don't have to use from_unixtime if your field is of type bigint and its milliseconds.